# XSLT: Check if a value in a nodeset exists in another nodeset

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

So, I have two variables each containing a nodeset (A and B). I need to do a count of rows in nodeset B where @id exists in nodeset A.

Is this possible and if so I'm not sure how to write this xpath in xslt 1.0?

```
<xsl:value-of select="count($B[])"/>
```

Comment: Can you show exactly how `A` and `B` are defined, as it may affect the answer given. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear from your question if this is quite what you need.  That said, this kind of problem is not uncommon.

Assuming data like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>
    <nodeset_a>
        <item id="1"/>
        <item id="2"/>
        <item id="3"/>
        <item id="4"/>
        <item id="2"/>
    </nodeset_a>
    <nodeset_b>
        <item id="1"/>
        <item id="4"/>
        <item id="5"/>
        <item id="6"/>
        <item id="7"/>
    </nodeset_b>
</test>
```

Your question makes it sound like you want to count how many items in `nodeset_b` have `id` values that match `id` values in `nodeset_a`.  The following expression will produce the correct count:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(/test/nodeset_b/item[@id = /test/nodeset_a/item/@id])"/>
```

#### Update - negation

The opposite can be a bit trickier -- looking for items in `nodeset_b` that have `id` values with *no* matching `id` values in `nodeset_a`.

At first glance, it might seem like the following is what you'd want:

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/test/nodeset_b/item[@id != /test/nodeset_a/item/@id]"/>
```

However, this doesn't work to solve our problem.

Breaking this down, what it does is to find all those `item` elements in `nodeset_b` that have an `id` value that doesn't match *one* of the `id` values in `nodeset_a`.  It doesn't matter which one: so long as there is any `id` value in `nodeset_a` that doesn't match, this XPath evaluation will return that `item` from `nodeset_b`.  For the `<test>` data above, this returns all of them, giving us a count of `5`.

To find all those `item` elements in `nodeset_b` that have an `id` value that doesn't match *any* of the `id` values in `nodeset_a`, we have to negate not just the equals sign, but instead the comparison expression itself:

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/test/nodeset_b/item[not(@id = /test/nodeset_a/item/@id)]"/>
```

For the `<test>` data above, this returns only those `item` elements from `nodeset_b` where the `id` value doesn't match *any* of the `id` values in `nodeset_a`, giving us a correct count of `3`.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is just what I was looking for.

Comment: In another report I'm now trying to show the rows in nodeset b that do not have a match in nodeset A. I tried <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Nodeset_B/Rows/Row[@id != $Nodeset_A/@id]"/> but that doesn't seem to work. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @MichaelBratley: I hope the **Update** section explains what you need.

Comment: That is perfect thanks so much, so simple really too. I did not think to use this.